# Get array's first item as object in TinkerPop3 Gremlin query and JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, graph-traversal

I faced this issue during a migration of gremlin queries from v2 to v3.

**V2-way**: `inE().has(some condition).outV().map().toList()[0]` will return an object. This is wrapped in `transform{label: it./etc/}` step.

**V3-way**, still WIP: `inE().has(some condition).outV().fold()` will return an array. This is wrapped in `project(...).by(...)` step.

V3 works fine, I just have to unwrap an item from the array manually. I wonder if there is a more sane approach (anyway, this feels like non-graph-friendly step).

Environment: JanusGraph, TinkerPop3+. For v2: Titan graph db and TinkerPop2+.

**Update:** V3 query sample

```
inE('edge1').
  has('cond1').outV(). // one vertex left
  project('items', 'count'). // pagination
    by(
      order().
        by('field1', decr).
          project('vertex_itself', 'vertex2', 'vertices3').
            by(identity()).
            by(outE('edge2').has('type', 'type1').limit(1).inV().fold()). // now this is empty array or single-element array, can we return element itself?
            by(inE('edge2').has('type', 'type2').outV().fold()).
          fold()).
    by(count())
```

Desired result shape:

```
[{
  items: [
    {vertex_itself: Object, vertex2: Object/null/empty, veroces3: Array},
    {}...
  ],
  cont: Number,
}]
```

**Problem:** `vertex2` property is always an array, empty or single-element.
**Expected:** `vertex2` to be object or null/empty.

**Update 2:** it turns out my query is not finished yet, it returns many object if there are no single element in `has('cond1').outV()` step, e.g. `[{items, count}, {items, count}...]`

Comment: Why there is `fold()` steps in `project().by(...fold())`? If I remove them I get an error `The provided traverser does not map to a value`

Comment: now I see that the question is very confusing, even initially given query is not working as described by myself. Let's close this one for now

Answer (score 3):

I may not fully understand, but it sounds like from this:

```
inE().has(some condition).outV().fold()
```

you want to just grab the first vertex you come across. If that's right, then is there a reason to `fold()` at all? maybe just do:

```
inE().has(some condition).outV().limit(1)
```

Comment: good point, I'll add it like this `inE().has(some condition).limit(1).outV()`. But still, `limit` step will return array with single element. Is it possible to get element itself OR null, not an array?

Comment: added question comment on `fold()` steps usage

Answer (score 3):

it looks like your main issue is getting a single item from the traversal.

you can do this with `next()`, which will retrieve the next element in the current traversal iteration:

```
inE().has(some condition).outV().next()
```

the iteratee's structure is, i think, implementation specific. e.g. in javascript, you can access the item with the `value` property:

```js
const result = await inE().has(some condition).outV().next();
const item = result.value;
```